# Opening a new jquery UI dialog causes an already existing iframe inside a jquery ui dialog to refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I open a jquery ui dialog with an iframe inside it.

The problem is that when I open another jquery ui dialog, the iframe reloads.

I don't want the iframe to be reloaded...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The case was that I was inserting a DIV on the "create" "event" of the dialog. DOM got changed and was the cause for IFRAME reloading.